# ArrayList<Contact> toString()

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I'm simulating a PhoneBook where i have an `ArrayList<Contact>`. How to overide the `toString()` function in order to have some thing like this wen doing `System.out.println(phonebook)`?

`Name: name1; Number: number1;
Name: name2; Number: number2;
Name: name3; Number: number3;
etc.....`

This worked:

`public String toString() { 
String phoneBookString = "";
for(Contact contact : list) { phoneBookString += contact.toString() + "\n"; } 
return phoneBookString; }`

Comment: Could you post the code of your `PhoneBook` class that you have written so far?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yarokas/9474707
https://gist.github.com/yarokas/9474700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own `toString()` method for a single object using [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) like this:

```
ArrayList<Contact> phonebook = new ArrayList<Contact>() {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: I had a bad feeling about extending a `List`. In this case it does seem to make sense, but I still wouldn't go it with it though.

Comment: My problem is how to implement the `for()` inside the `toString()`.
Because, if i understand, i need to return a only one `String`.

Comment: @user3403611 First define a single `StringBuilder str`, then iterate over individual elements of the list using `for (Contact c : this)` and for each element, append a new line to `str`. After the cycle, return `str.toString()`.

Comment: Made this:
`public String toString() {
 String phoneBookString = "";
 for(Contact contact : list) {
  phoneBookString += contact.toString() + "\n";
 }
 return phoneBookString;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the `toString()` method of `Contact` first:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "your string representation";
}
```

And then when printing out this code, your `phonebook`, you want to do do a `for`-loop:

```
for (Contact contact : phonebook) {
    System.out.println(contact);
}
```

It might be worth considering making `Phonebook` an own class, such that you could implement its own `toString()` method.

An extra, when using Java 8, you could do the following instead of writing 3 lines of code you could write it in one longer line:

```
phonebook.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will call `System.out.println(T)`, resolved to `System.out.println(Phonebook)`, for all your `Contact` instances in `phonebook`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have `toString` of an `ArrayList` behave differently then the `ArrayList`'s built-in `toString`, you can define your own subclass:

```
class ContactList extends ArrayList<Contact> {
    // duplicate the constructors in ArrayList
    public ContactList() { super(); }
    public ContactList(Collection<? extends E> c) { super(c); }
    public ContactList(int initialCapacity) { super(initialCapacity); }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // your version
    }
}
```

Now you can create objects of type `ContactList`, and they will behave just like an `ArrayList<Contact>` except that `toString()` will behave differently.

However, if your plan is for this to be used **only** inside some other `PhoneBook` class, then it's not worth the effort; best to write a private method inside `PhoneBook`:

```
private String toString(ArrayList<Contact> a) { ... }
```

and use that instead.  (That would be the case if you have a PhoneBook class that has a private `ArrayList<Contact>` member, and your only use of this is to write the `toString()` of your `PhoneBook` class.  There's no real need to write an overriding `toString()` for the `ArrayList<Contact>` member; just write a utility method to create the string you want.)

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no nice way to @Override the toString() method of ArrayList.
but there are other nice options:

**Suggestion number one:**
Override the toString() method of the object the in your list.
ArrayList automatically invokes the toString of the enclosing types to print string representation of elements.
then you can do this:

```
// Converting ArrayList to String using Spring API , result is comma separated String       
String phonebookToString = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(phonebook);

System.out.println("String converted from ArrayList : " + phonebookToString);
```

or this:

```
String phonebookString = "";

for (Phone p : phonebook)
{
    phonebookString += p.toString() + "\t";
}

System.out.println(phonebookString);
```

**Suggestion number two:**
Write static method

```
static void phoneBookToString(ArrayList<Phone> phonebook) { ... }
```

that do what i write in suggestion number one.